# Which databases does `mysqlpump` ignore by default?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

If I run the following command:

```
mysqlpump > mysqlpump.sql
```

Is there any documentation, a SQL query that can be run, or perhaps a config file that contains a complete list of databases that `mysqlpump` ignores by default?

According to this [Percona blog post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/17/the-mysqlpump-utility/), the following databases are ignored by default:

- INFORMATION_SCHEMA
- ndbinfo
- performance_schema
- sys

However, this list was written in 2017 and seems incomplete. I've seen other documentation which indicates that `mysqlpump` also ignores tables in the `mysql` database.

Comment: Can't you `grep` the dump file for the `CREATE DATABASE...` statement?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to know is to test, on Percona Server for MySQL 5.7.28 (latest as of this writing) it shows that mysqlpump includes the mysql schema in the backup:

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `mysql` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `mytest` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `test` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
```

Comment: Percona Server is available at least through 8.0.18 (2019-12-11).